# fopen error for creating a new file?

Tags: php

I was following a guide for creating a new file in php and I was using the following code:

```html
    function create($user, $name) {
  /* Later on, this will connect to another server*/
  $dir = $user->getFolder() . "/Projects/". $name;
  if(file_exists($dir)) {
   $this->error = "Directory: " . $dir . " already exists.";
  } else {
   mkdir($dir);
   //Create the users.json file and add the owner
   $json = fopen($dir . "/Data/users.txt", "w") or die("Cannot open file");
   fclose($json);
  }
 }
```

The directory gets created but I receive the following error: "Warning: fopen(Jake/UserFolder//Projects/test/Data/users.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\Collabs\Objects\Scripts\Project.php on line 14
Cannot open file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path shown in your error looks like it could be the problem.

> Jake/UserFolder//Projects/test/Data/users.txt

There are two slashes between UserFolder and Projects. It looks like changing your code to

```
$dir = $user->getFolder() . "Projects/". $name;
```

Would get rid of the extra slash.

Comment: Omg. Wow I can't believe I did that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Did that fix the problem? It occurred to me after posting the answer that it seems like that path would have caused problems with the `mkdir` as well and you said that was working.

Comment: It did, and afterwards I noticed that the '/Data/' was not created... lol so it was what I found and what you found

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that might have gone wrong:

1. You didn't pass path with a leading `/`, so `fopen()` will search relatively to the directory the script is executing in. I assume you'll want to pass an absolute path
2. you are testing for `file_exists()`, you should also check for `is_dir()`, to catch and handle the cases where a file with the same path already exists
3. you might consider calling `mkdir($dir, 077, true)` in order to create 
   the intermediary directories (see the [mkdir() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php))